# Why null pointer instead of class cast?

Tags: java, language-design

In Java:

```
int count = (Integer) null;
```

throws a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Why doesn't this throw a Class Cast Exception for ease in programmer understanding?

Why was this exception chosen over any other exception?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When executing your code, the Java runtime does the following:

1. Cast null to an object of class Integer.
2. Try to unbox the Integer object to an int by calling the method intValue()
3. Calling a method on a null object throws a NullPointerException.

In other words, null can be cast to Integer without a problem, but a null integer object cannot be converted to a value of type int.

**EDIT**

I had a related question a while ago at Stack Overflow, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588856/conversion-from-null-to-int-possible).

Answer (score 1):

Java successfully casts null to an Integer reference that references no object.

That's OK because being unistantiated is a valid state for a reference.

It's the calling of a method of a non existing object that can't be performed.

Performing the cast `(Integer)null` is the same as declaring an Integer variable and then failing to assign it an new (or already existing) Integer object instance.

Answer (score -1):

To unbox a `Integer` into a `int` i.e. in `int i = new Integer(15);`, `i` actually equals `new Integer(15).intValue()` `i  = (Integer) o`; where `Object o = 15` is the same as `o = Integer.valueOf(15);` but `i = null`; throws an `NullPointerException` because `i` then equals  `null.intValue()` which throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The answer that was accepted almost two years ago provides almost the same explanation, but is more clear. This answer is also not correct for Java 5+: it now uses the `valueOf()` factory methods rather than creating new instances for boxing.